# Yii Query not executing the same as Mysql Client

Tags: yii, query-builder

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    i.id, 
    i.title, 
    i.slug, 
    i.date_added as date_added,
    a.slug as area_slug, 
    COUNT(o.id) as offers, 
    COUNT(v.item_id) as total_item_views
FROM 
    `item` `i`
LEFT JOIN 
    `offer` `o` 
ON 
    i.id=o.item_id
LEFT JOIN 
    `viewed_item` `v` 
ON 
    i.id=v.item_id
INNER JOIN 
    `a` `a` 
ON 
    a.id=i.area_id
WHERE 
    j.id=3
```

It works fine inside PHPMyAdmin. I converted it to Yii so it looks like this:

```
        $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $cmd->select(array('i.id, i.title, i.slug, i.date_added as date_added, a.slug as area_slug, COUNT(o.id) as offers, COUNT(v.item_id) as total_item_views'));
    $cmd->from('item as i');
    $cmd->leftJoin('offers as o', 'i.id=o.item_id');
    $cmd->leftJoin('viewed_item as v', 'i.id=v.item_id');
    $cmd->join('area as a', 'a.id=i.area_id');
    $cmd->where('i.id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));

    $basicStatModel = $cmd->query();
```

This works fine in cases where the 'viewed_item' table has a record equal to $id value being used for this query. Currently viewed_item only has 2 records, but their are multiple records in the item table. I'm looking at my stack though and it shows this:

ViewedItem.findByPk()

Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM `viewed_item` `t` WHERE `t`.`id`='3' LIMIT 1

Currently there is no ID equal to 3 in that table, so i'm guessing that's why the page errors. But at the same time i'm not sure why it's looking for an ID value in that table. I can see that it's using the findByPK() method. However I've asked it to find essentially a FK in the SQL statement.

How do I fix this problem? It's thrown me that the SQL works inside of PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: you have `$cmd->from('item as i');` and `$cmd->leftJoin('viewed_item as i'` in your YII, is it a typo or did you alias the tables wrong

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo. I've edited it above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right!

The problem was within my controller code. The query executes properly. This query

```
Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM viewed_item t WHERE t.id='3' LIMIT 1
```

Was actually just existing Gii generated code in the view() method within the controller.

Appreciate the help and time Patrick!

Thanks

Jonny